# Are sine and cosine the only sinusoidal functions?

Tags: functions

I came across sinusoidal functions while studying physics (waves and oscillations)

Comment: What's your definition of sinusoidal function?

Comment: $f(x)=\text{real}(e^{xi})$

Comment: I would guess $\sin(x+k)$ counts as sinusoidal for any constant $k$.

Comment: Have you heard about Fourier series?

Comment: @Julien: *read but not understood it well*

Comment: *A sinusoidal function is one which repeats itself after a fixed peroid, for example, the sine function repeats itself after 2 (pi)

Comment: @Lakhi So, to answer your question, there are infinitely many functions that repeat themselves after a fixed period. However (as far as I know) they can all be decomposed into a series made up entirely of sine and cosine functions. Even non-differentiable things, like the sawtooth, can be decomposed into sines and cosines.

Comment: @Julien: k so any other function would be a combination of sine and cosine functions

Comment: @Lakhi Yes. You might need infinitely many of them, though. In practice, it's not always useful to think about things that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$(x-2\lfloor\frac{x}{2}\rfloor)^2(2-x+2\lfloor\frac{x}{2}\rfloor)^2$ is not bad. Period 2.

[image]

Comment: I may be wrong, but any generalized $a$-sinusoidal function works as well: $\left(x-a\left\lfloor\frac{x}{a}\right\rfloor\right)^a\left(a-x+a \left\lfloor\frac{x}{a}\right\rfloor\right)^a$

Comment: Well, I wouldn't go too high on the exponents - 3 is quite pretty - but otherwise, yes. This was just quickly chosen to peak at 1, really.

Comment: Oh, I see that.

Comment: A little bit more fiddling gives 2.4 as an exponent that closely tracks a trig function for shape.

Answer (score 1):

For example the general equation for an exponentially damped sinusoid may be represented as:

$$y(t)=Ae^{-\lambda t}\cos(\omega t + \phi)$$

where

$y(t)$ is the instantaneous amplitude at time t.

$A$ is the initial amplitude of the envelope.

$\lambda$ is the decay constant, in the reciprocal of the time units of the $X$ axis.

$\omega$ is the Angular frequency.

And $\phi$ is the phase angle at $t=0$.